# What is" $PARTITIONNAME" for installing Anbox on Ubuntu16.04(Ubuntu Touch)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

everyone. I am installing Anbox to Ubuntu16.04 OTA-9.
I am following direction of installing Anbox here(http://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/anbox.html). And I'd like to do this command.

```
sudo fastboot flash $PARTITIONNAME anbox-boot-$CODENAME.img
```

But I cannot understand what is $PARTITIONNAME here. Could you tell me what it is?

Thanks
Daisuke

Comment: Your link says it is the `name of the boot partition for your device` from the table at the top of the link - so either `boot`or `bootimg` depending on what you put between the quotes when you entered `export CODENAME="turbo" && export PARTITIONNAME="bootimg"`.  What device `CODENAME`are you using?

Comment: My device CODENAME is Hammerhead (Nexus5). What is the PRTITIONNAME for it?

Comment: `boot`.  It is right there in your link `Nexus 5 (codename: hammerhead, name of the boot partition: boot)`

Comment: @lx07 It works! Thank you!